# Hide a div element when other div is not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I hide a div element when a other div element with a specifiv ID is not found?

For example if this div is not found in the whole HTML-Code:

```
<div id="found">I'm here</div>
```

then hide following div:

```
<div id="hide-me">Hello World</div>
```

The best solution to solve this might be with a script

Comment: aaand you tried what exactly? I see you know it can be done using JS, so what was your research and why it did not worked. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: use javascript or jquery .on method

Comment: The problem is that i have no clue about javascript or jquery

Comment: @amit what? why?

Comment: He has not mentioned that he wants it on page load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Div is not hiding via CSS after showing and hiding a div using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866498/div-is-not-hiding-via-css-after-showing-and-hiding-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: @PeterGriffin well than if you want to solve this I suggest getting some clues about javascript and jquery. This site is not for teaching basics, but solving specific problems.

Comment: Sorry Maciej Jureczko. But JS looks so complicated to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems pretty easy. When you search for an element with jQuery, the `length` property indicates how many elements were found.

```
jQuery(function($) { // run when the document is "ready"
  if ($('#found').length === 0) {
    $('#hide-me').hide()
  }
})
```

Comment: how about `if (!$('#found').length)`

Comment: @AminJafari if you're happy with implicit boolean conversion then sure, go for it

Comment: Thank you very much Phil :-)

Comment: @AminJafari `=== 0 ` is *programmer-friendly*. You lean back and you see it. If you're codegolfing and every bit is crucial.... than you would not use the jQuery library in the first place :D

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){
  if($('#found').length==0)
    $('#hide-me').hide();
})
```

try this.

Comment: I'm the downvoter. This answer already exists - and in a better format.

Answer (score -4):

```
 $find_div = jQuery(document).find('#found');
 if($find_div){
    jQuery(document).find('#hide-me').show();
 }else{
   jQuery(document).find('#hide-me').hide();
 }
```

Comment: `$find_div` will **always** be *truthy*. This will always run `.show()` even if `#found` is not, err, found

Comment: And why you use `jQuery` all over the place? jQuery has a nice `$` shorthand.

Comment: Also `jQuery(document).find('#hide-me').show();` is not the way you should write jQuery.